# How to replace 'nil' with a value using sub

Tags: ruby, string, substitution

I am trying to substitute a nil value with something using sub but it isn't happening. Where am I wrong.

```
a=""
a.sub!(//,"replaced")
puts a #=> "replaced"

b=nil
b.to_s.sub!(//,"replaced")  #tried => (b.to_s).sub!(//,"replaced") but didnt work
puts b #=> nil
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Nil is nil: there's nothing to replace.

Comment: @dave: `b.to_s.nil? => false`

Comment: Obviously, you turned it into something that isn't nil-a string representation of the nil object. I guess I'm missing your point. What's important is `nil.nil?`. Just because you can make a substitution in a strong reservation of something doesn't mean it will be reflected in the original object-`to_s` can return whatever it wants.

Comment: I am trying substitute a var with a value (in place). And I see a different behaviour when the var has empty string and when it has `nil` converted to string (empty string).

Comment: Because `nil` is nil, not a string. I don't understand the issue. If you want `b` to be something other than nil, you need to set it. Nil's to_s returns a new string with "nil" inside it. As I said, to_s can return *anything*, and in general, doing things to that string will not affect the underlying object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help you understand what is happening, let's follow your code statement by statement:

```
a=""                       # create a new string object (the empty string), assign it to a
a.sub!(//,"replaced")      # sub! changes this very string object
puts a #=> "replaced"      # the changed string is printed

b=nil                      # we assign nil to b
b.to_s.sub!(//,"replaced") # this is actually two steps
                           # nil.to_s creates a new string object "" (the empty string)
                           # .sub! modifies that new string object in place
                           # the edited string is not assigned to anything, it will be garbage collected later
puts b #=> nil             # b is still assigned to nil
```

We observe that `b` itself is never changed by `sub!`. Solely the object returned by `b.to_s` is changed (but then discarded).

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to initialize b? The idiomatic Ruby way to initialize is :

```
b ||= "replaced"
```

Comment: Not as usual as I'd like ;)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do to `b.to_s`, it is a different object from `b`, so `b` is not modified, and stays to be `nil`, as assigned initially.

And there is no way to change `nil` into a string using `gsub!`. That method is defined on `String`, not on `NilClass`. However, you can reassign `b` to a string just by doing `b = whatever_string`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning `b` to the new value "replaced".

```
b = b.to_s.sub!(//,"replaced")
```

will help you out otherwise it'll stay `nil` this is due to `to_s` providing a temporary representation of your `b` object and thusly `sub!` will not affect `b` at all.

Evidence:

```
s = "monkey"
s.sub!('m', 'd')
>> "donkey"
```

Answer (score 0):

`nil` and the empty string isn't the same thing, `nil` is not a string, and thus it doesn't have the `sub!` method. However `nil.to_s` gives the empty string, and your code works 
fine here.

```
irb(main):007:0> b=nil
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> b.to_s.sub!(//,"replaced")
=> "replaced"
```

Your code doesn't work, because you don't assign the result back to `b`:

```
b = nil
b = b.to_s.sub(//,"replaced")
puts b
```

you need to do this, because, to_s creates a copy of `b`, which isn't referenced anywhere, and that is the string that sub! changes.

Another solution is to check if b is nil, and set it to "":

```
b = "" if b.nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
irb(main):006:0> b = b.to_s.sub(//, "123")
    => "123"
```

What version of Ruby do you use?

By the way, can you provide more details about what you're doing, because that seems a little weird to me. Maybe we'll give you more appropriate advice.

Comment: I am not doing anything specific. Trying to learn ruby. That's all.